# Check collision of 2 objects in libgdx

Tags: libgdx

I am making a game in libgdx, where you shoot aliens with bullets. I have 2 `ArrayList`s of objects and would like to check if any of objects in `bulletArrayList` is colliding with any object from `alienArrayList`. What is the best way to do that? I was thinking of `contactListener`.

In the screen class I am generating objects like this:

```java
public class PlayScreen implements Screen, InputProcessor,ContactListener {

    public ArrayList<Alien> alienArrayList = new ArrayList<Alien>();
    public ArrayList<Bullet> bulletArrayList = new ArrayList<Bullet>();


    public void generateAlien() {
        alien = new Alien();
        alienArrayList.add(alien);
    }

    public void shootBullet(float x, float y) {
        //send x,y moving coordiantes
        bullet = new Bullet(x,y);
        bulletArrayList.add(bullet);
    }
}
```

In object class I have `Rectangle` box which i am moving like this:

```js
public class Alien {

    public Alien() {
        bound = new Rectangle( x, y, alienRegion.getRegionWidth(), alienRegion.getRegionHeight());

    }

    public void update(float delta) {
        bound.y -= speed * delta;
    }

    public void render(SpriteBatch batch, float delta) {
        update(delta);
        elapsedTime += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        alienRegion = (TextureRegion) alien.getKeyFrame(elapsedTime, true);
        batch.draw(alienRegion, getBound().x, getBound().y);
    }
}
```

Comment: We are going to need much more details than what you have provided. Are you using Box2D, collision detection shapes? Do you have any code that you have written which shows research?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are using `Rectangle`s in your `Alien` class, we can use a class called `Intersector` which has static methods to check for collision detection.

```
for(Alien alien1: alienArrayList) {
        for(Alien alien2 : bulletArrayList) {
            if(Intersector.overlaps(alien1.rect, alien2.rect)) {
                // Collision code
            }
        }
}
```

First, we iterate through the two lists using a *nested special for* loop. Then we pass two `Rectangle`s to the `Intersector.overlaps(rect1, rect2)`. This is a static method defined in the `Intersector` class which will return true if the rectangles are overlapping.

Also, this code can go straight into your `render` method.

This code is not the most optimized because it will check 2 rects twice however, I will leave the optimization to you.

I hope that this answer was helpful and if you have any further questions please feel free to post a comment below.

Comment: This approach will be ok for slow enough objects. But since the OP deals with bullets, he will probably need more accurate ways, because of the "tunneling effect".

Comment: if I understand correctly, in that case I have to extend rectangle class in Alien? On collision i want to change textureAtlas -> animation of that object, which (correct me if im wrong) i can not do, since an object is now Rectangle..

Comment: Sorry, I made an error in the code above. I changed it so that it iterates through the aliens and then accesses the rects. To change the animation that is being played I usually just set a public field to `true`. Such as `alien1.isCollided = true`. In the `update` method of the `Alien` class make sure that this field is taken into account when deciding what animation to play. Hope this makes some sense to you!